# Setting up a rule to cancel a scheduled rule?

Tags: rules, ubercart

We have an ubercart store where users who successfully check out are immediately given roles that provide access to purchase. The checkout process runs into an occasional issue where an order will get stuck in pending state due to some PayPal glitch.

I want to set up a notification to admins when this Pending issue happens. The problem is that during a checkout that successfully completes, orders are momentarily given "Pending" status...so I can't just set up a notification that user is in "Pending" status, or we'll get a message every time someone purchases.

One solution would be to create a rule/condition that schedules an email every time an order receives "Pending" status (i.e. every order triggers this)...email would be scheduled to be sent, say, 20 minutes after that event. And then, have a second rule that cancels the scheduled email as soon as that order attains completed status.

Is the above implementation possible? Or any ideas for a more straightforward way to do this?

Thanks!